# Failed Tls connection to LND with gRPC and REST using rust

Tags: lightning-network, network, lightning-network-daemon, grpc

I have been trying to connect to an LND node using Rust as a language.
I have been constantly be given this error:

```
tonic::transport::Error(Transport, hyper::Error(Connect, Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificate(Other(CaUsedAsEndEntity)) }))'
```

I decided to take a look and see how *[lncli](https://github.com/lightninglabs/lightning-terminal)* (built in golang) does this I encountered this two functions:

NewClientTLSFromFile comes from google.golang.org/grpc/credentials

AppendCertsFromPEM comes from https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509

```
   # certFile is just the route to the tls.cert provided by LND
  func NewClientTLSFromFile(certFile, serverNameOverride string) (TransportCredentials, error) {
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(certFile)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        cp := x509.NewCertPool()
        if !cp.AppendCertsFromPEM(b) {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("credentials: failed to append certificates")
        }
        println("RootCAs: ", cp)
        return NewTLS(&tls.Config{ServerName: serverNameOverride, RootCAs: cp}), nil
    }

    func (s *CertPool) AppendCertsFromPEM(pemCerts []byte) (ok bool) {
        for len(pemCerts) > 0 {
            var block *pem.Block
            block, pemCerts = pem.Decode(pemCerts)
            if block == nil {
                break
            }
            if block.Type != "CERTIFICATE" || len(block.Headers) != 0 {
                continue
            }
    
            certBytes := block.Bytes
            cert, err := ParseCertificate(certBytes)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }
            var lazyCert struct {
                sync.Once
                v *Certificate
            }
            s.addCertFunc(sha256.Sum224(cert.Raw), string(cert.RawSubject), func() (*Certificate, error) {
                lazyCert.Do(func() {
                    // This can't fail, as the same bytes already parsed above.
                    lazyCert.v, _ = ParseCertificate(certBytes)
                    certBytes = nil
                })
                return lazyCert.v, nil
            })
            ok = true
        }
    
        return ok
    }
```

I have been breaking my head on how to do this in RUST but I haven't been able figure it out.
sorry if this is a bad explanation.

Comment: Lots and lots and lots of people use Rust to make TLS connections to things other than LND - any of them might solve your problem. They mostly hang out in stackoverflow.com rather than bitcoin.stackexchange.com. That might be a place to get a faster answer.

Comment: just did that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76497734/grpc-connection-error-causedasendentity-using-rust-tonic
thank you for the suggestion!